# playing with references and pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to learn C++ and I'm  having some difficulties learning pointers and references. I'm trying to understand why some of the below do not work, and I cannot seem to figure out the difference between "double *const ptd" and "const double *ctd"

```
double d;
  const double r; //bad; r must be initialised
  const double pi = 3.1416;
  double *ptr = &pi; //illegal to point to a constant, because otherwise one could change the value of the constant which defies the purpose of a constant
  double *const cpt; //bad; cpt must be initialised
  double *const ptd = &d;
  const double *ctd = &d;
  const double *ptc = &pi;
  double *const ptp = &pi; //illegal
  const double *const ppi = &pi; 
  double * const * pptr1 = &ptc;
  double * const * pptr2 = &ptd;

  void F () {
    ptr = new double;
    r = 1.0;
    *ptr = 2.0;
    cpt = new double;
    *cpt = 3.0;
    ptc = new double;
    *ptc = 4.0;
    ptd = new double;
    *ptd = 5.0;
    ctd = new double;
    *ctd = 6.0;
    ptp = new double;
    *ptp = 7.0;
    ppi = new double;
    *ppi = 8.0;
  }
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double * const` (read as "constant pointer") means that the pointer is constant. You can't modify it, but you can change the object that it points to.

`const double *` or `double const *` (read as "pointer to constant") means that the pointer can't be used to change the object it points to; but the pointer itself can be modified.

In general, the `const` qualifies the thing immediately *before* it; or the first thing, if there's nothing before it.

Comment: perfect. Thank you. Know I am starting to get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

`const double *ctd`:

- it means a **pointer** (an address much like a integer value indicating the beginning of a memory zone) which is **not constant** ( this adresse value can change so as to point to another zone of memory, for example `ctd = nullptr;`) **pointing to a const double**..., the double that is pointed will never change its value.

`double *const ptd`:

- it means a **const pointer**(an address much like a const integer value indicating the beginning of a memory zone) which is **constant** ( this address value CANNOT change so as to point to anything else)  **pointing to a double** which value can change.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, about the difference between `double * const ptr` and `const double * ptr`. 
The first one (`double * const ptr`) makes a constant pointer `ptr` which should point to `double`. The pointer itself is const, what it points to is *not* const.

The second variant (`const double * ptr`) makes a pointer that should point to a `const double`. In this case it's the opposite: the pointer itself is not const, but what it points to *is* const.

Now, considering the errors you are getting (I'll go from top to bottom):

- `const double r;` - you need to initialize constants, like this: `const double r = 15`;
- `double *ptr = &pi;` - You are basically making a pointer to `r`. Since `r` is `const`, the pointer must be a pointer to `const double`, not just `double`.  The correct one will be `const double *ptr = &pi;`
- `double *const cpt;` - uninitialized constant again, same as the first one. All constants *must* be initialized. Something like `double *const cpt = new double` will do.
- `double *const ptp = &pi;` - same as the second one. Your *pointer* here is const, but it has to point at a normal `double`. Instead, you are truing to make it point on a `const double`, which leads to an error. `const double *const ptp = &pi;` will work.
- `double * const * pptr1 = &ptc;` Here you are trying to make a pointer `pptr1` which should point to a pointer to a double.

Comment: You mean `double * const ptr`, not `double const * ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

- `const double * x` is the same as `double const * x`.

  - It means **"`x` points to a `double` that is immutable"**
  - that is, the `double` value can't be changed via `x`
- `double * const y`

  - means **"`y` is an immutable pointer to a `double`"**
  - you can change the `double` value via `y`
  - but you can't change the pointer `y` itself (i.e. cannot point to another memory location)
- There's also `const double * const z` (or `double const * const z`)

  - means **"`z` is an immutable pointer to an immutable `double`"**
  - you can't change the pointer `z` itself
  - nor can you change the value via `z`.

In all the cases, `const` qualifies the thing immediately before it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that part of the problem might be ambiguities in the `const` syntax. The rule is ***const applies to whatever is on its immediate left (other than if there is nothing there in which case it applies to whatever is its immediate right)***

So `const T` is the same as `T const`, but `T const *` ist not the same as `T * const`.

This gets worse in understanding when you have several `const` in a type.

Therefore I will usually always put the `const` to the right of the type it applies to, to be consistent.

As most people will see examples like `const int` as the first examples for using constness, it probably puzzles them a lot later on where to put the `const`